# How do I enable e-mail in a Salesforce sandbox org?

Tags: email

I'm trying to get started with e-mail templates, etc. and I want to test these things in my sandbox org rather than interfere with any production data by mistake.

If I go onto a Lead record in the production org, I see the "Email" tab under "Activity":

[image]

But if I do the same on the sandbox org, it's not there:

[image]

I've compared every setting under Setup > Administration > Email between the production and sandbox orgs and all of the settings are the same in both. I paid special attention to Deliverability since it sounded like aspects of this could throw a spanner in the works, but this is all the same too (other than Access Level which I have already changed to All email):

[image]

I'm logged in as the administrator user, so I don't see why permissions would factor into this, either.

I saw a post on the Salesforce boards that suggested e-mail isn't enabled for the sandbox org, but I can't find where I can enable it. Any insight into my situation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If email is not enabled in your sandbox follow below steps:

1. Setup
2. Email to Salesforce
3. Activate

If it is enabled than in order to add email tab to activity component

Make sure buttons for New Task, New Event, Log a Call, and Send an Email (not Send Email) are added to the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section of the page layout

Comment: Not really no, Email to Salesforce is for adding emails to your salesforce records.  If you are only sending email from your instance then you can skip that step. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Doh! When I checked what you said, I manged to look at the org where it was already working. That did it. Thanks.